# How to make Excel print selective tabs using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I already coded my Excel workbook to print out all of my selective sheets that I need all at once.  However, there are times where I will only need it to print specific sheets instead of all of them.  Is there a way that before I print I can have my code ask me what range of sheets I want to print so I am not getting all 45 when I just need 7?  Thank you in advance.

Chris

```
Sub PrintWorksheets()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Feedback Data" Then
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then

            ws.PrintOut

        End If
    End If
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "All charts have been printed Mark"


End Sub
```

Comment: As far as I know there really isn't any built-in tool for selecting sheets to print, unless your pages are sequential and you don't need them by name. If you need to choose them by name, you're best off creating a Userform where you either populate a listbox with all your sheet names (then print the selected ones), or manually create checkboxes - which might be messy with 45 pages.

Comment: @dwirony havent made many userforms before, but if you're going for broke Chris you might consider making it look like the interface to add things to the quick access toolbar https://www.wikihow.com/images/thumb/2/25/Customize-the-Quick-Access-Toolbar-in-Microsoft-Word-%28Windows-7%29-Step-3.jpg/aid3171921-v4-728px-Customize-the-Quick-Access-Toolbar-in-Microsoft-Word-%28Windows-7%29-Step-3.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of a `UserForm` where we populate a `ListBox` with the names of all sheets in the file:

[image: img1]

Code behind the `UserForm`:

```
Dim i As Long
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    ListBox1.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
Next i

End Sub
Private Sub btnPrint_Click()

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ListBox1.List(i)).PrintOut
    End If
Next i

End Sub
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Naturally, there are other facets to this, such as changing the `ListBox`'s `MultiSelect` property to `1` (to allow multiple sheets to be selected), and in my example I rename my buttons out of practice. But this is how you would solve your problem, in theory.

Comment: Nice solution, dwirony.  However, you might want to change `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` to `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count`.  Otherwise you might get unexpected results if the workbook includes other sheets, such as a Chart sheet.

Comment: @Domenic Good call - I've made the change.

Comment: `If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True` can be reduced to `If ListBox1.Selected(i)`

Comment: @JohnyL Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create more subroutines, each having different **predefined** set of sheets to select. Examples:

```
Public Sub selectSheets_1()
    Dim arrayOfNames As Variant
    arrayOfNames = Array(ws1.Name, ws2.Name, ws4.Name)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arrayOfNames).Select
End Sub


Public Sub selectSheets_2()
    Dim arrayOfNames As Variant
    arrayOfNames = Array(ws8.Name, ws15.Name, ws25.Name, ws35.Name, ws45.Name)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arrayOfNames).Select
End Sub
```

And so on...
Where `ws#` is the codename of sheet.